# How would I make a cookie to save the position of these div tags?

Tags: javascript, cookies, html

I am using JQuery to have the ability to reorder my divs (code below), but I need to make a cookie to save the order of these divs. I see alot of site coming up with Javascript stuff, but its usually saying things like save an inputted name and such. I have no clue how to go about doing this.

```
$().ready(function() {
    $('.moveUpCls').click(function(event){
      var current = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
      current.prev().before(current);
    });
    $('.moveDownCls').click(function(){
      var current = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
      current.next().after(current);
    });
});
```

Each moveable div follows this pattern (The div's also have hide/show on em, but ignore that for the time being):

```
<div>
    <div id="tabHeader">

        <div id="headMoveUp"><a class="moveUpCls"><img src="images/uparrow.png"></a></div>
        <div id="headMoveDown"><a class="moveDownCls"><img src="images/downarrow.png"></a></div>
        <a href="javascript:toggle();"><div id="tabHeadText">Important Links &raquo;</div> </a>

    </div>
        <div id="toggleText" style="display:none; text-align:center;">
            <div id="empGuide" style="text-align:center;margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">

                CONTENT OF DIV

            </div>
        </div>
        <br />

</div>
```

Comment: Give each div a unique id. After a moveUp/moveDown click, grab the current order of the divs, and save it as a string (myOrder = '4,12,2,1'). Write this string to your cookie.

Comment: so the div before <div id="tabHeader"> ?   
This is my first jump into cookies, so elaboration would be great!

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a JSON representation of your layout, but beware, cookies can only hold 4K of data. You're best storing it on the server or using local storage.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the number of permutations, you could create a hash of key->value pairs in your jquery code, where each value would be an ordering of the the divs, and the key would be what you store in the cookie.